# AngularJS mixed content with templateUrl on directive when using a HTTPS redirect

Tags: angularjs

On my back-end I have a redirect that changes my page to be served via HTTPS.
Specifically this is a Spring back-end that uses a url-mapping file to handle redirects.

When using an angular templateUrl on a directive with a relative path (e.g., templateUrl: 'web/app/my-page.html' I get a mixed-content error.

Is angular not designed to handle this automatically?  All of my other includes (e.g., angular.js, jquery.js) are fetched appropriately using HTTPS.

Comment: Further testing:  specified the full domain for templateUrl:  'https ://domain.com/web/app/my-page.html' and it still attempts to serve the .html from http://.

Comment: So, the `index.html` (for your main page) is served from HTTPS?

Comment: Well, the page with the angular app on it is served via HTTPS. This HTTPS is handled by a redirect that says any HTTP request to my page should be served via HTTPS.  All other links (like angular.js and jquery.js) are correctly fetched via HTTPS.  Even hard-coding the whole path to 'https://...etc...' is still fetching the templateURL from 'http://...etc..'.

Comment: I'm still not sure why this was happening.  What I'm going to do is get around it by using gulp's ngHtml2js plugin to create a template cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this was happening. What I did to get around it is to use gulp's ngHtml2js plugin to create a template cache.  This prevents the need for XHR requests.